# Updating data with same primary key

Tags: c#, sql

I am reading data from csv file and adding data in database. At time of inserting data into database I want to update data with same primary key.

e.g.) I am using two Columns Bar-codes (PK) and Quantity. So, when I insert data from csv file similar barcode quantity will get added.

Can anyone help me? I am using C#.NET and SQL.

Thanks,
Rushabh Shah.

Comment: What are you using to access the databases?  Entity Framework, nHibernate, DataSets/Readers calling stored procs, Linq to Sql, etc...?

Comment: Is this for any SQL type or do you need for a specific DB?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I am designing windows application and using data grid view to display data.

Comment: Do you mean by "quantity will be added" that it must be added to the quantity already existing (e.g. already 2 in the DB, new quantity =4, result in the DB will be 6) or must the value in the DB be changed to 4?

Answer (score 2):

check out the [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) keyword. it should do pretty much waht you're asking for.

here's a stored proc that should do it for you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertBarcodeData
    @Barcode varchar(255),
    @Quantity int
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE myTableName AS target
    USING (SELECT @Barcode, @Quantity) AS source (BarCode, Quantity)
    ON (target.Barcode= source.Barcode)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Quantity = source.Quantity + target.Quantity
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (BarCode, Quantity)
        VALUES (source.BarCode, source.Quantity)
END;
GO
```

Comment: I am new to the merge. Is it also possible with the merge command to update SET Q = source.Q + Q?

Comment: @Pleun - Yes it can update using exiting values. The MERGE statement is crazy flexible. Almost....*too* flexible. :-D

Comment: what @jeffrey said.  the update portion works almost exactly like a regular update statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
create procedure InsertOrUpdateSales
(
    @bar_code nvarchar(100),
    @quantity int
)
as
if exists (select * from sales where bar_code = @bar_code)
  update sales set quantity = quantity + @quantity where bar_code = @bar_code
else
  insert into sales ( bar_code, quantity) values ( @bar_code, @quantity )
go
```

And

```
public static void InsertOrUpdateSales(string connection, string barCode, int quantity)
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("InsertOrUpdateSales", conn))
        {
             comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             comm.Paramters.AddWithValue("@bar_code", barCode);
             comm.Paramters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity);
             comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the merge statement (as @Chris Lively and @nathan gonzalez mentioned) you could get really fancy and do it like this:

1. BULK INSERT the data from the CSV file to an empty temp table.
2. MERGE the temp table with the existing table.
3. TRUNCATE the temp table.

This might give you the best results. (For certain values of "best".)

Comment: ONLY do this method IF you are using an older version of SQL Server which does not support the MERGE statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that there is already an existing entry for all of the bar codes in the table you could do this with a Stored procedure with two incominig parameters (@BarCodeID and @AdditionalQuantity)

`UPDATE yourTable SET Quantity = Quantity + @AdditionalQuantity WHERE BarCode = @BarCodeID`

Comment: i think the issue is that he can't guarantee that, and thus would like to update if necessary, or insert if not.

Comment: @Nathan In that case I concede that The Merge solution is better.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to the table.  When ever something is inserted in the table, you can have it run a stored procedure.

Comment: what?  downvoting for nonsensical answer